# Auto Create MySQL Tables on First Run Java/MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to Auto create SQL tables on first run, and haven't found any good tutorial on google. Does anyone have a suggestion or can explain it to me. My class so far looks like:  http://pastebin.com/6u8yFWrt

Comment: You didn't mentioned, what type of application you developing. Is it Java EE or Java SE? You can run SQL DDL query on first run.

Comment: Standard Edition, my fault for not mentioning. I get lost in my little world some times.

Comment: You can use JDBC or Hibernate to auto create tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mysql you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename IF NOT EXISTS...
```

This will, as the name says, create the table if there is no table with the same name, described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html). If you run it whenever you open the connection to the database, you should be fine.

BUT this is no guarantee that the existing table has the format you want! If you change the definition of the table halfway through the process, because you want an extra column, you will need to delete the existing table fist, for the changes in the query to have an effect.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to do this from inside java code. It is for a plugin and I want it to auto-create it for my users. Thanks for the quick response and its detail! Maybe you will have another way to do it?! Thanks again!

Comment: Even in Java you use normal SQL-queries, just the way to connect to the database is different (JDBC driver etc.). You will need to call some methd like execute (I don't know the exact name) and pass a valid SQL-query as the parameter. After you open the connection (which you will have to do somewhere), you can execute this statement for every table you want to auto-create. @user3251224

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use JPA and Hibernate instead. Youre probably in for quite a journey until you get the hold of it but I think it is worth the effort.